# Confusing hand in a Texas Hold em

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-history

Me and My friends were playing a game of texas hold em when this hand came out. Player 1 ended up taking the hand, but I'm still confused. Is high card still applied when both players have the same two pair?
P1: 7,A
p2: 7,J

7, Q, Q, 2, 3

Comment: Yes it still applies